# How to applying regex to replace values

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace

I have a dataframe province like this :

```
province = {'province':['Prov. Jawa Barat', 'JAWA BARAT', 'Prop. Jawa Barat', 'Prov. Sumarta Selatan', 'SUMARTA SELATAN', 'Prop. Sumatra Selatan'],
            'city':['Bandung', 'Bogor', 'Cimahi', 'Palembang', 'Solo', 'Cilacap']}

df_prov = pd.DataFrame(province)
```

However, the names of the provinces do not have the same rules. So how to change the name of the province with the prefix 'Prov' and 'Prop' to JAWA BARAT and SUMARTA SELATAN?

Sorry I don't speak English very well
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try simply removing the prefix and uppercasing what remains:

```py
df_prov["province"] = df_prov["province"].str.replace(r'^Pro[pv]\. ', '').str.upper()
```

Comment: But I have about 34 province names like that, it is very tiring to change them one by one.

Comment: @InsanCahya If you know for certain that _all_ province names starting with `Prop.` or `Prov.` would need to have that prefix stripped and the rest upper cased, then see my updated answer.  Otherwise, we would need a list of all provinces which you want to target.